# holomorphic functions on Stein manifolds reaching maxima in a given point on the boundary (Shilov boundary)

Tags: complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables, complex-manifolds, stein-manifolds

Let $M$ be a Stein manifold with smooth, strictly
pseudoconvex boundary, and $x$ a point on its
boundary. Is there a holomorphic function $f$ on
$M$, smooth on the boundary, with strict
maximum of $|f|$ in $x$?

This question was treated for domains in ${\mathbb C}^n$,
but I could not find any reference for bigger generality.

**Update**. The set of maxima is called "Shilov boundary".
For domains in ${\mathbb C}^n$, Shilov boundary is the
set of strictly pseudoconvex points on the boundary, as follows
from the papers

Richard F. Basener,
*Peak Points, Barriers and Pseudoconvex Boundary Points,*
Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society Vol. 65, No. 1 (Jul., 1977), pp. 89-92.
https://www.jstor.org/stable/2041997

M. Hakim and N. Sibony, *Frontiere de Silov et spectre de A(D) pour des domaines faiblement pseudoconvexes,* C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris 281, Serie A (1975), 959-962.

Comment: I think the term for the set of points where such peaks occur is Shilov boundary.

Comment: Many thanks! That's right, now I also remember that term. More stuff to google, then

Comment: ...and for a domain in C^n, Shilov boundary is the set
of strictly pseudoconvex points,
https://www.jstor.org/stable/2041997
Peak Points, Barriers and Pseudoconvex Boundary Points
Richard F. Basener
Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society
Vol. 65, No. 1 (Jul., 1977), pp. 89-92